# Is there anyway that we can count the number of lines & comments in an Xcode Project?

Tags: xcode8

I need to know the total number of lines and comments of Xcode project.

I have tried CLOC .

CLOC failed to give the result i was looking for.

Please respond!

Answer (score 0):

I would do this in **Bash**...

Go to the directory your files are in and do something like this.

Assuming the files you want are `.swift` files.

```
find YOUR_DIR_HERE -name '*.swift' | xargs wc -l
```